# FilePond in Vue - Customize Headers

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, filepond

I'm currently using [FilePond](https://github.com/pqina/filepond) via the [Vue-Adapter](https://github.com/pqina/vue-filepond) in my app and it's working fine.

My current, for this question relevant, code looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <v-layout>
    <v-flex class="text-center">
      <FilePond
        ref="pond"
        name="file"
        chunk-uploads="true"
        :chunk-size="chunkSize"
        class-name="my-pond"
        label-idle="Drop files here..."
        :allow-multiple="allowMultiple"
        :files="myFiles"
        :server="server"
        @init="handleFilePondInit"
        @error="error"
        @processfile="updatefiles"
        @addfile="testlog"
      />
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

The `server`-Property looks like this:

```js
  computed: {
    headers() {
      return {
        Authorization: this.$auth.getToken('local'),
        projectId: this.projectId,
      };
    },
    server() {
      return {
        url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/filepond/',
        process: {
          url: 'process',
          headers: this.headers,
        },
        patch: {
          url: 'patch?id=',
          headers: this.headers,
        },
      };
    },
    chunkSize() {
      return this.$config.chunk_size_byte;
    },
  },
```

This setup does work fine. FilePond works as intended and my custom headers get injected additionally to the headers FilePond provides. Now I ran into an issue, where I need the Filename also on a `process`-Request, which doesn't usually get sent when a `patch`-Request follows.

I found [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/pqina/filepond/issues/409), which is basically my exact issue.

If I however change my computed `server`-value to the following code, my headers don't get applied at all.

```js
    server() {
      return {
        url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/filepond/',
        process: {
          url: 'process',
          headers: (file, metaData) => ({
            Authorization: this.$auth.getToken('local'),
            projectId: this.projectId,
            filename: file.filename,
          }),
        },
        patch: {
          url: 'patch?id=',
          headers: this.headers,
        },
      };
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying a lot out, it seems like there's a bug with `vue-filepond`, where custom Header-Functions are only applied, when uploading files with `fileSize > chunkSize`.

I opened an issue and Rik provided a workaround for the time being (https://github.com/pqina/vue-filepond/issues/193).